# I created invoive using angular 11.and template driven form

Tags: angular

[image]

I display items, total amount in my invoice ,but when i console this total amount always i got emty field.
i try lot of methods to slove this, but i cannot do this, so how can i pass the total amount value into my console.when i type any total amount and console log I can display my type value, but In this case i cannot console log, the value comming from my function. How can i fix this??

my home.component.html is,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" >INVOICE</a>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid pt-2" style="margin-bottom: 250px">

      <div class="card border-secondary">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Invoice Details</h4>
          <form #invoiceinformation="ngForm" >
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Issued Person Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="personName" id="name" [(ngModel)]="InvoiceObject.personName" #name="ngModel" required>

                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name.valid">
                  <span *ngIf="name?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
                </div>


              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Invoice Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="invoiceDate" id="date" [(ngModel)]="InvoiceObject.invoiceDate"  #name1="ngModel"   required>

                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name1.valid">
                  <span *ngIf="name1?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="invoiceNo">Invoice No</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoiceNo" id="invoiceNo" [(ngModel)]="InvoiceObject.invoiceNo"  #name2="ngModel" required>

                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name2.valid">
                  <span *ngIf="name2?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="TAmount">Total Amount</label>


                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="totalAmount" id="TAmount" [ngModel]="getInvoiceTotalAmount()"  >

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card border-secondary mt-2 mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between">Items Details <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRow()">+</button></h4>


          <form action="" #invoiceBody="ngForm">
            <div *ngFor="let obj of itemsArray;let i=index">
          <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Item No</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemNo{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.itemNo" #name3="ngModel"   required >

              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name3.valid">
                <span *ngIf="name3?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Unit Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="unitPrice{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.unitPrice" #name4="ngModel"   required>

              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name4.valid">
                <span *ngIf="name4?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Quantity</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.quantity" #name5="ngModel"   required>

              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name5.valid">
                <span *ngIf="name5?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label>Total</label><br>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total{{i}}"  [ngModel]="updateTotalInItemsArray(obj)">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="i!=0">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top:30px" (click)="removeRow(i)">-</button>
            </div>



           </div>

          </div>


          </form>


          </div>

        </div>


<!--  [hidden]="!invoiceinformation.valid" [disabled]="!invoiceBody.valid"-->

      <button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="addInvoiceInformation();addInvoiceBody()"   >Add To Database</button>



</div>
```

my home.component.ts file is,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import {InvoiceService} from "../../invoice.service";



class itemObject {
  itemNo:any;
  unitPrice:number=0;
  quantity:number=0;
  total:number=0;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

InvoiceObject={
  personName:"",
  invoiceDate:"",
  invoiceNo:"",
  totalAmount:0
}



itemObject=new itemObject()
itemsArray:Array<itemObject>=[
  {
    itemNo:"",
    unitPrice:0,
    quantity:0,
    total:0

  }
]


  constructor(private invoiceService:InvoiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  addInvoiceInformation() {

        console.log(this.InvoiceObject)
        this.invoiceService.addInvoiceInformationInToDatabase(this.InvoiceObject).subscribe(result=>{
           console.log(result)
     })

  }

  addInvoiceBody() {
  console.log(this.itemsArray)
  this.invoiceService.addInvoiceBodyInToDatabase(this.itemsArray).subscribe(result=>{
    console.log(result)
  })


  }

  addRow() {
    this.itemsArray.push(this.itemObject)


  }

  removeRow(i: number) {
    this.itemsArray.splice(i)

  }


  getInvoiceTotalAmount() {
    return this.itemsArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc += this.updateTotalInItemsArray(item);
      return acc;
    }, 0)

  }


  updateTotalInItemsArray(item: itemObject) {
    item.total =(item.quantity && item.unitPrice) ? item.quantity * item.unitPrice:0;
    return item.total
  }





}
```

**plz help me to do this**

Comment: can you create a stackblitz  / online sandbox of your code ?

Comment: didn't understand ??

Comment: if you want to do just console log , just assign a value in a variable then console log on next line and then add return statement.  and for better understanding what you are trying to do achieve. i am suggesting to add your code https://stackblitz.com/ so that one can see running example

Comment: i dont have idea that you are told me

Comment: can you send me the answe if u can???

Comment: `addRow() {this.itemsArray.push(this.itemObject) }`should be `this.itemsArray.push(new itemObject())` for avoiding overwritting

Comment: thnx bro this my another problem

Comment: bro can u suggest a method to console log the total amount

Comment: total amount value is display in total amount input field, but i console log this i always comming empty field, so how can i console log this total amount value??